# How do I run personalized Page Rank by pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, pagerank

I want to set node 1 as start node to implement personalized Page Rank. how should I add the start node?

```
import networkx as nx
from operator import add

link_data = {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [2, 6],
    2: [1, 0],
    3: [1, 0],
    4: [1],
    5: [0, 1],
    6: [0, 7],
    7: [0, 1, 2, 3, 9],
    8: [5, 9],
    9: [7]
}
link_graph = nx.DiGraph(link_data)

ranks = sc.range(len(link_data)).map(lambda x : (x, 1.))
links = sc.parallelize(link_data.items()).cache()
links.join(ranks).collect()

def computeContribs(node_urls_rank):
    _, (urls, rank) = node_urls_rank
    nb_urls = len(urls)
    for url in urls:
        yield url, rank / nb_urls

for iteration in range(10):
    contribs = links.join(ranks).flatMap(computeContribs)
    contribs = links.fullOuterJoin(contribs).mapValues(lambda x : x[1] or 0.0)
    ranks = contribs.reduceByKey(add)
    ranks = ranks.mapValues(lambda rank: rank * 0.85 + 0.15)

for (link, rank) in sorted(ranks.collect()):
    print("%s has rank: %s." % (link, rank / len(link_data)))
```

Is there somebody who can help me? where I should set the sourceId personalizes the results for that vertex.thanks!!